# Why was a flag on this "I have this problem too" answer declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer, specific-answer

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15682309/712603) is, in my view, an "I have this problem too" post, but my flag as "Not an answer" was declined.

The text of the answer is:

> I also have this problem with Samsung galaxy Tab 2 (with Samsung keyboard). In fullscreen mode (after GridView.setAdapter()) it cause nasty bug - activity slightly dragging to bottom on start. I added textNoSuggestions to editBox but it doesn't help. Then i add to manifest android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" and it works, but only for start case. If i will run next activity from that and go back - bug reappears. Layout:

followed by the layout of the XML.

I don't mind having the declined flag- my question is whether posts like this should be considered an answer. My only guess as to why it might be declined is the sentence:

> Then i add to manifest android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" and it works, but only for start case.

This does seem to provide part of the answer, or perhaps a hint towards it. I often see answers that do provide a bit of extra information ("I'm having this problem too, but not when I use version 2.3.9", or "I'm having this problem too, but only when I run at least 30 queries per minute") without answering the question. These would make great comments, but they are usually posted by users without 50 rep. My impression is that such posts should be flagged, and am curious whether this declined flag indicates otherwise.

Should this specific answer be considered "Not an answer"? And more generally, do answers that report "I have this problem too," but do provide some useful information, count as "Not an answer"?

Comment: The answer does contain a partial solution, so it isn't NAA. I believe that is reserved for when there is no attempt at an answer within the body of the post.

Comment: It reads to me like a response, not an answer, @Asad; "I tried this and this and still had the same problem" might be good added to the question, but doesn't really help in the answer space.

Comment: @JoshCaswell "I tried this and this and it *fixed the problem*, temporarily". Then he proceeds to provide the layout that partially fixes the problem.

Comment: That is really walking the line between answer and not.

Comment: The question is pretty obviously a NARQ too. A question about what info the OP needs to gather to ask a question.

Comment: In general, if the author even nods in the direction of something that they _think_ will resolve the OP's problem, I avoid Not An Answer in favor of it simply being a bad answer. So in this case I'd call it a (bad) answer. But maybe I'm being too strict.

Comment: @joran: how would you feel about an answer like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699761/android-s3-layout-vs-galaxy-nexus-layout/14509393#14509393)?

Comment: _Personally_ if I had something like that to say, I keep it in a comment. But I wouldn't flag that as NAA, I'd just choose between (1) down voting, (2) leaving a comment, (3) editing it, (4) ignoring it. Like I said, I'm typically very strict about what's NAA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was me who declined the flag. Coming back to it, you are right. Sorry, for not seeing it in the first place. There is quite a lot of flags to handle lately and I probably didn't give it the right amount of time. I guess that's what distinguishes me from a robot. Andrew rightfully deleted it.

Comment: Cool! Like I said, I was just interested in how I should treat similar cases in the future, and it sounds like flagging is reasonable.

Answer (score 5):

I can see how that one would seem to be an answer, as it does 'flirt' with a solution. However, the condition on the solution seem to suggest it's not a solution after all. I did not know it had a previous flag that was declined, so just judged on the content.

I am open to being told I was wrong, but I agree with your flag, obviously.

Comment: The fact the answer contains *"doing X temporarily works until I do Y"* makes it seem valid to me, although it is by no means a very complete or even good answer. But if I was experiencing the same problem and the accepted answer didn't work, I would find that answer useful as it provides some more information about the exact nature of the problem by a user that has experienced the exact same problem. I'd probably try to convert the non-code part of it to a comment instead of deleting it outright.

Comment: I think it might be an issue with phrasing. The way that the answer is organized, it starts and ends with "I have a bug", such that it really does seem to be asking a question. If it had started with "You can fix this problem temporarily with... though this is only a temporary solution because..." I wouldn't have considered it NAA.